# Java and substring error

Tags: java, indexing, substring

I am implementing a method to encrypt with a key and i made a call like this:

```
Crypto c = new Crypto("mysecretkey");
String enc = c.encrypt("mytext");
```

But i am getting an exception

> "crypto encrypt error: String index out of range: -1"

at this part:

```
String sKeyChar = getKey().substring((i % getKey().length()) - 1, 1);
```

And I don't know what I am doing wrong because I made the same thing in PHP and works good. Maybe this is simple but I am stuck, this is my method:

```
public String encrypt(String sData) {
        String sEncrypted = null;
        try {
            String sResult = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < sData.length(); i++) {
                String sChar = sData.substring(i, 1);
                String sKeyChar = getKey().substring((i % getKey().length()) - 1, 1);
                char c = (char) (ord(sChar) - ord(sKeyChar));
                String sPart = (new StringBuffer().append(c)).toString();
                sResult += sPart;
            }
            byte[] sResultBuff = sResult.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sEncrypted = Base64.encode(sResultBuff);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("crypto encrypt error: " + e.getMessage());
            sEncrypted = null;
        }
        return sEncrypted;
    }
```

Other method needed:

```
public int ord(String sChar) {
    int ascii_code = 0;
    try {
        ascii_code = String.valueOf(sChar.charAt(0)).codePointAt(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("crypto ord error: " + e.getMessage());
        ascii_code = 0;
    }
    return ascii_code;
}
```

PHP equivalent method:

```
function encrypt($sData, $sKey='mysecretkey'){ 
    $sResult = ''; 
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($sData);$i++){ 
        $sChar    = substr($sData, $i, 1); 
        $sKeyChar = substr($sKey, ($i % strlen($sKey)) - 1, 1); 
        $sChar    = chr(ord($sChar) + ord($sKeyChar)); 
        $sResult .= $sChar; 
    } 
    return encode_base64($sResult); 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should post `getKey()` method as well, as it is used in line, which fails.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking this isn't cryptographically secure?  I feel like I should be able to divine the key and the data from this, knowing the method (supposing short keys).  And that's assuming that the result of the subtraction operation is a valid `char`, anyways; that `ord()` method doesn't always return valid data, and isn't international safe (combined characters).  Also, you're swallowing `Exception`s, which is _bad_, and simply _printing_ to `System.out` (and not even `.err`!), instead of properly logging.  And look up `StringBuilder` - your implementation is not optimal.

Comment: Thanks for recomendations but this is just a test method and getKey() works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the difference between PHP and Java because PHP's `substr` understands negative numbers, but Java's `substring` does not: it throws an exception.

In PHP, passing negative 1 to `substr` means "get me the last character", but in Java you need to pass the index of the last character (i.e. `str.length()-1`) to achieve the same effect.

If this is not a mistake, and this is precisely the effect that you wanted to achieve, you can address this issue with an `if` condition:

```
int pos = (i % getKey().length()) - 1;
if (pos == -1) {
    pos = getKey().length() - 1;
}
// EDIT: Second argument needs to be pos+1, not 1. Thomas pointed out this error
String sKeyChar = getKey().substring(pos, pos+1);
```

**EDIT** As Thomas correctly pointed out, the other difference between PHP version of `substr` and Java's `substring` is in their treatment of the second argument: PHP thinks it's length; Java thinks it's the index of the last character plus one.

Comment: That would produce an exception if `pos` was not 0 or 1.

Comment: @Thomas You are absolutely right, that's the other difference between PHP and Java. At this point I think your solution (going with individual characters rather than one-character strings) is a lot cleaner, so I'm upvoting it. Thanks for finding this bug!

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) I still getting an error at this line "char c = (char) (ord(sChar) - ord(sKeyChar));" in the ord() method but I will continue looking for what is happening. But everything clear, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is wrong: `(i % getKey().length()) - 1` will result in -1 for `i = 0`, i.e. right in the first iteration. Thus you try to pass -1 to the `substring(...)` method, which is not allowed.

Also note that if the data is longer than the key, `i % getKey().length()` will result in 0 for every multiple of the key length.

Additionally, the parameters to `substring(...)` are not `index` and `length` but `startIndex` (inclusive) and `endIndex` (exclusive). Thus `String sChar = sData.substring(i, 1);` will throw an exception once `i` reaches 2 (and above) and won't return anything for `i = 1`.

You might want to use `charAt(i)` instead (and `getKey().charAt(i % getKey().length())` in the following line). Note that this returns a single character, which would make the `ord(...)` method obsolete.

As a side note: `String.valueOf(sChar.charAt(0)).codePointAt(0)` is equivalent to `sChar.codePointAt(0)`.

Another side note:

```
char c = (char) (ord(sChar) - ord(sKeyChar));
String sPart = (new StringBuffer().append(c)).toString();
sResult += sPart;
```

can be simplified to

```
char c = (char) (ord(sChar) - ord(sKeyChar));
sResult += c; //you could also merge those two lines
```

Comment: If someone's going to rate me down, it would be nice to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, substr in PHP has different semantics that in Java.
In PHP its

`string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`
and it also accepts negative numbers (which alter it's behaviour),

while in java it's defined as:

```
 String     substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

and throws exception on negative numbers or if `beginIndex` is greater than `endIndex`.
To summarize, they are different and you need to compensate for that.